# Efficient algorithms to split and join lines?

Tags: python, algorithm, line, splitting

Referring to the Figure below:

1. How to efficiently join segments into lines?
2. How to efficiently break lines into segments?

The above will be applied million times.

[image]

Comment: What GIS software is involved?  If none, can you say so and give more details of what you are looking for here, please?

Comment: Are the lines and the points (where split has to take place) topologically connected? Do you know which points are present on a given line?

Comment: @PolyGeo None. We will code in `Python`. The points above are intersection points with many other lines that are removed later. So our interest is to split each line to many segments based on the intersecting points (part left). Our another interest is reversing the act, that is having a series of aligned (parallel) segments to join them as one line if possible (part right).

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe Right, even after splitting the will have points in common. The gaps above (part left) are only for demonstration. We don't have a record of belonging points to a specific line. Indeed, the inputs are segments (or lines for question 2) and points. We drew them here together for demonstration.

Comment: Maybe wrong but why don't you use a spatial DB like PostGIS or Spatialite. More efficient if you use spatial index on your tables and low level. Built-in operations for your need FYI

Comment: @ThomasG77 Yeah, they are of course tools doing this perfectly. We prefer however to implement ourselves as so we are looking for some efficient algorithms rather than packages/software. We do it now as we explained to `Kirk Kuykendall` using `dict` in `Python`. It does job but there is efficiency issue as we will apply it on millions of lines.

Comment: This is standard material in computational geometry textbooks, which would likely be a better resource for the low-level implementation you are looking for.  Both problems are most efficiently solved using (*inter alia*) a line-sweep algorithm, such as the [Bentley-Ottmann algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bentley%E2%80%93Ottmann_algorithm).  GIS users are always insulated from these implementation details; the closest they get are "spatial indices," which are--in one form or another--persistent versions of data structures used to perform efficient searches.

Answer (score 9):

You can use effectively Shapely, and [Fiona](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Fiona) to read a shapefile for example:

```
import fiona
# open a line shapefile
file = fiona.open('lines.shp')
# first element of the shapefile
first = file.next
print first
{'geometry': {'type': 'LineString', 'coordinates': [(203317.23, 90448.75), (203679.62, 90105.68), (203882.57, 89902.74), (204143.49, 89641.81), (204394.75, 89385.72), (204563.87, 89235.93)]}, 'id': '0', 'properties': {u'id': "1"}}
```

Now import Shapely

```
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString, shape
geom = shape(first['geometry'])
# now it is a Shapely geometry
print geom
LINESTRING (203317.23 90448.75, 203679.62 90105.68, 203882.57 89902.74, 204143.49 89641.81, 204394.75 89385.72, 204563.87 89235.93)
```

**Splitting**

**We can split the line in segments**, each pair of coordinates (Point) define a line segment:

```
def pair(list):
    '''Iterate over pairs in a list -> pair of points '''
    for i in range(1, len(list)):
        yield list[i-1], list[i]

for seg_start, seg_end in pair(geom.coords):
    line_start = Point(seg_start)
    line_end = Point(seg_end)
    segment = LineString([line_start.coords[0],line_end.coords[0]])
    print segment
LINESTRING (203317.23 90448.75, 203679.62 90105.68)
LINESTRING (203679.62 90105.68, 203882.57 89902.74)
LINESTRING (203882.57 89902.74, 204143.49 89641.81)
LINESTRING (204143.49 89641.81, 204394.75 89385.72)
LINESTRING (204394.75 89385.72, 204563.87 89235.93)
```

You could do it directly with Fiona:

```
for seg_start, seg_end in paires(first['geometry']['coordinates']):
    ....
```

**Union**

1. If the line is straight, simply use the first and the last point to make the LineString

   LINESTRING (203317.23 90448.75, 204563.87 89235.93)
2. In other cases, with shapely, you can use union, cascaded_union(geoms) or unary_union(geoms) and the result is a MULTILINESTRING;

With union:

```
line = LineString()
for element in line['geometry']['coordinates']:
   geom =shape(line['geometry'])
   profile = profile.union(geom)
print line
MULTILINESTRING ((203317.23 90448.75, 203679.62 90105.68), (203679.62 90105.68, 203882.57 89902.74), (203882.57 89902.74, 204143.49 89641.81), (204143.49 89641.81, 204394.756 89385.72), (204394.75 89385.72, 204563.87 89235.93))
```

or directly with shapely:

```
line = LineString()
for seg_start, seg_end in paires(geom.coords):
     line = line.union(LineString([Point(seg_start).coords[0],Point(seg_end).coords[0]]))
```

**Intersection**

The shapely function is geom1.intersection(geom2)

1. for two straight lines, it is simply

   line1.intersection(line2) # the result is a Point
2. for two lines with segments, it is

   (union of segments of line1).intersection(union of segments of line2) # the result is a Point or a MultiPoint (more than a single intersection)

And saving the results is easy with Fiona

Comment: Please note that we **don't** know which point belongs to which line. Line segments are **not** listed in any order. They are randomly located in an array. If you know which line is aligned (next) to a line, joining them is not an issue. But notice that we **don't** have any topology information of lines. No information between points and lines.

Comment: This answer is so misleading. To break any edge in a line segment, you need to know whether a point is ON that edge first.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Shapely can answer what you are expecting.
See the [manual](http://toblerity.github.io/shapely/manual.html).
Create lines using native objects.
For what you need, only loop ;) to get segments of a line.
For getting intersection point, use operators like intersection

I can't say that is efficient but I suppose that because Shapely uses Geos behind, it's quite fast.

Comment: We are not sure about that either. In our previous attempts for another issue we noticed however `Shapely` was 10 times slower than our mixed `Python`-`Fortran` implementation.

Answer (score 1):

To join line segments you can assign a `from-node#` and a `to-node#` to each line segment, where the node# is a hash of x and y rounded off.  For example, a point at `123.45,567.8` might be computed to be `123568`.  This implies a tolerance of 1.  You could generalize this to round off to the closest multiple of the tolerance.

Once you have From and To node#'s, you can [topologically sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) the segments. This can be done by building a valence count for each node with a dictionary where the key is node# and the value is `valence` (the number of segments that share the node).  Start at a node whose valence == 1 and walk until you reach another node whose valence==1, connecting the dots in other words. You can then use the topologically sorted list to build an ordered list of coordinates, i.e. a polyline.

Update:  See whuber's similar question [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/11041/59).

Comment: If you wish to go further, it is the mathematical area of Planar Graphs ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graphs)) implemented in OpenJump ([link](http://www.openjump.org/)

Comment: Indeed, we have already implemented a similar idea in `Python` using `defaultdict`. This is not efficient as you need to update the dictionary entirely after joining every two segments.

Comment: @gene I don't think this approach requires the graph to be planar, does it?

Comment: @Developer I wouldn't join two segments at a time, but rather just list the coordinates for each chain of edges after sorting.