# Splitting Line.shp at Point.shp with Python/ogr

Tags: python, linestring, splitting

I'm trying to modify some ESRI Shapefiles using Python with gdal/ogr module.
What I want to do is quite simple, but I didn't find any solution by now.

I have two shapefiles: (1) Lines.shp and (2) Points.shp
The features of the Points.shp mark intersections of the lines in the Lines.shp

Is there any way to split the line-features at the given points?

edit: It should work like the "Split Line at Point"-tool from ArcMap
(Data Manangement Tools --> Features --> Split Line at Point)

edit2: I already knew about the [other topic](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61474/efficient-algorithms-to-split-and-join-lines), but I don't want to use shapely. Also I don't want to save my Points into a list. I just wanted to know, if tehre is any function/method like ESRIs "Split Line at Point"

Comment: I do not know how to use it but OGR Layer algebra is probably what you need http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/rfc39_ogr_layer_algebra

Comment: Already answered here:https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61474/efficient-algorithms-to-split-and-join-lines