# Split lines at points using Shapely

Tags: shapely, splitting, geopandas

I'm trying to split a shapefile of geometry type 'line' at a shapefile of geometry type 'point. These points are snapped to the lines and are the start points/end points of other line shapefiles.

Something like this : 
The points are snapped to the **black** lines.

[image: splitAtPoints]

As of now I'm working with Geopandas/Shapely/Fiona.
I've searched for a native function in Shapely that performs the split; however, I've had no luck in finding a solution. This is also true when searching through Shapely's official docs. 
This is odd since the split is among the basic geoprocessing tools.

My goal is to give a function of the two shapefiles (lines & points) and split the lines at points (like ArcGIS' tool). The split lines should then be stored in a different shapefile.
This seems easy to do but the lack of documentation is a bump in the road.

Any ideas on how I can do this in python using Geopandas/Shapely?

Answer (score 19):

You have many solutions and I use here a simple example

1) the easiest way

```
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString
line = LineString([(1,2),(2,4),(4,5)])
point = Point(2,4)
```

First, you must determine if the  point is within the line ([Determine if shapely point is within a linestring/multilinestring](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21295192/835653))

```
line.distance(point) < 1e-8
True
print LineString([line.coords[0],point.coords[:][0]])
LINESTRING (1 2, 2 4)
print LineString([point.coords[:][0], line.coords[-1]])
LINESTRING (2 4, 4 5)
```

2) with the shapely function `split`

```
from shapely.ops import split
result = split(line, point)
result.wkt
'GEOMETRYCOLLECTION (LINESTRING (1 2, 2 4), LINESTRING (2 4, 4 5))'
```

3) from [Get the vertices on a LineString either side of a Point](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21419035/835653)

```
from shapely.geometry import Point,LineString    
def split(line_string, point):
    coords = line_string.coords
    j = None    
    for i in range(len(coords) - 1):
        if LineString(coords[i:i + 2]).intersects(point):
           j = i
           break    
    assert j is not None    
    # Make sure to always include the point in the first group
    if Point(coords[j + 1:j + 2]).equals(point):
        return coords[:j + 2], coords[j + 1:]
    else:
        return coords[:j + 1], coords[j:]

line1,line2 = split(line,point)
line1 = LineString(line1)
line2 = LineString(line2)
print line1, line2
LINESTRING (1 2, 2 4) LINESTRING (2 4, 4 5)
```

4) from [Shapely Split LineStrings at Intersections with other LineStrings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34770395/835653)

```
# First coords of line (start + end)
coords = [line.coords[0], line.coords[-1]] 
# Add the coords from the points
coords += point.coords
# Calculate the distance along the line for each point
dists = [line.project(Point(p)) for p in coords]
# sort the coordinates
coords = [p for (d, p) in sorted(zip(dists, coords))]
lines = [LineString([coords[i], coords[i+1]]) for i in range(len(coords)-1)]
for lin in lines:
   print lin
LINESTRING (1 2, 2 4)
LINESTRING (2 4, 4 5)
```

5) you can also examine and adapt

- [cut.py](https://gist.github.com/sgillies/465156#file_cut.py) by Sean Gillies
- [Efficient algorithms to split and join lines?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/61551/2581)
- [Shapely: Cut a piece from a linestring at two cutting points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31072945/shapely-cut-a-piece-from-a-linestring-at-two-cutting-points)
- ....

Comment: Thank you @gene for your detailed answer! At first I was looking for a native function in Shapely that does that.

Comment: The function `split`

Comment: The split function in Shapely is not recognized apparently. I tried importing : from shapely.ops import split
But I get an unresolved error. I install the split package and nothing happens still. Very odd. I already have the points and lines in shapefiles so all I need to do is the split. The point are already projected on the lines.

Comment: look at the github version of shapely [ops.py](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/blob/master/shapely/ops.pyp) line 329

Comment: Yes I have seen it. That's why I don't understand why it's not recognized once imported.

Comment: from shapely.ops import split
ImportError: cannot import name split

Comment: Upgrade Shapely

Comment: Done that. Already upgraded :/

Comment: from what I can tell `split` is not in the current release of shapely (1.5.17) it [looks like](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/issues/293) they're planning to add it to the 1.6 release

Comment: To make from shapely.ops import split working, use <pip install https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/archive/master.zip> to install the latest shapely version. At the time of writing it is Shapely-1.6.dev0

Comment: The `split` function could be nice, but no matter how I try to snap the point onto the line, it won't split the line at that point.