# Splitting MultiLine or LineString into equal segments of particular length using GeoPandas and shapely

Tags: python, line, geopandas, splitting, linestring

I don't have a license for any software. So, I want to do it in Python.

How do I split the multiline or any linestring into equal segments by taking the length as input?

This is the code that I am using

```py
import geopandas as gpd    
from shapely.ops import split
from shapely.geometry import LineString, MultiPoint

roads = roads['geometry'] # roads contain a single multiline
points = points['geometry'] # points for finding the distance from line segements after segmenting the multiline

plot = roads.iloc[0] # roads.iloc[0] gives a multiline
x = plot.length
x = int(x/0.2)
splitter = MultiPoint([plot.interpolate((i/x), normalized=True) for i in range(1, x)])
#splitter gives the points on multiline at equal distance, but only contains points
plot = gpd.GeoSeries(plot)
splitter = gpd.GeoSeries(splitter)
```

Comment: What did you find or tried because unless you add a Python code attempt your question will be closed

Comment: @gene please check now if there is anything that you can help me with. Thank you

Comment: You want to split each line into for example 10 equal length segments, or each line into for example 20 m long segments? It would be alot easier to use QGIS which have got the finished tools for this

Comment: @BERA I want to split line into segments of 500m each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many questions/answers in gis.stackexchange ans stackoverflow on this subject

Some of them
[Splitting line shapefile into segments of equal length using Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/250784/splitting-line-shapefile-into-segments-of-equal-length-using-python)
[Break a shapely Linestring at multiple points](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/210220/break-a-shapely-linestring-at-multiple-points)
[Shapely: Split LineString at arbitrary point along edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50332273/shapely-split-linestring-at-arbitrary-point-along-edge)
[Split lines at points using Shapely](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/203048/split-lines-at-points-using-shapely)
[Splitting line GeoDataFrame basing on given lengths](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/386482/splitting-line-geodataframe-basing-on-given-lengths)

Example with a single shapely LineString and creation of equidistant points(from [How to get equally spaced points on a line in Shapely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62994304/835653))

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString, Point
import numpy as np
line = LineString(([0, 0], [2, 1], [3, 2], [3.5, 1], [5, 2]))
distance_delta = 0.9
# generate the equidistant points
distances = np.arange(0, line.length, distance_delta)
points = MultiPoint([line.interpolate(distance) for distance in distances] + [line.boundary[1]])
print(len(distances), len(points))
8 9
```

[image]

Now, due to floating point issues in Shapely, I use the solution of [Jeremiah England](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/386527/2581) with `shapely.ops.snap` before `shapely.ops.split`

```
 from shapely.ops import split,snap
 def split_line_by_point(line, point, tolerance: float=1.0e-12):
     return split(snap(line, point, tolerance), point)
 result = split_line_by_point(line,points)
 print len(result)
 8  # 8 segments
```

[image]

You can also use the solution of [Grigory Nevsky](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/414888/2581) based on the function `cut(line, distance)` in the [The Shapely User Manual](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#linear-referencing-methods)

```
 def cut(line, distance, lines):
     # Cuts a line in several segments at a distance from its starting point
     if distance <= 0.0 or distance >= line.length:
         return [LineString(line)]
     coords = list(line.coords)
     for i, p in enumerate(coords):
         pd = line.project(Point(p))
         if pd == distance:
             return [
                 LineString(coords[:i+1]),
                 LineString(coords[i:])
                 ]
         if pd > distance:
             cp = line.interpolate(distance)
             lines.append(LineString(coords[:i] + [(cp.x, cp.y)]))
             line = LineString([(cp.x, cp.y)] + coords[i:])
             if line.length > distance:
                 cut(line, distance, lines)
             else:
                 lines.append(LineString([(cp.x, cp.y)] + coords[i:]))
             return lines

 result = cut(line, distance_delta, list())
 print len(result)
 8  # 8 segments
```

Comment: For people looking in 2023 - in the Shapely 2.0.1 there is [function `shapely.segmentize`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/shapely.segmentize.html)  that will do that: `segmentize(geometry, max_segment_length, **kwargs)` - adds vertices to line segments based on maximum segment length.